# Word 2007 .docx -cannot save document

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I received a .docx document from a fellow student which I can open but not save again even when I have made no edits whatsoever. When I press Save As the dialog appears, I write in a file name and press Save. The dialog now reappears and there is a empty Word file created with the file name I gave.

Any suggestions on how to recover my document?

P.S. It seems to be every file I get from this student and that equations are causing the problem but only some blocks of equations. If these are deleted the file becomes saveable.

Comment: It seems to be equations causing the problem

Comment: It seems that student is restricting changes to the document. Can you ask him to check if he has any restrictions set under Review tab?

Comment: I will ask that. It seems to be only some blocks of equations causing the problems. If you delete these, it becomes saveable.